# Import only needed records from Sybase to SQL Server using import wizard

Tags: sql

I need to pull in a set of Sybase records into a SQL Server table and I'm going to do this using the import wizard in SSMS 2014.  There are 4.5 million records in the Sybase table, but I only need less than 40K of them.  There is an associated ID field in both databases, so in theory I could select the information I need for only the records I have, and not import the entire 4.5 million.

I would like to do the equivalent of this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sybase table] WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT * FROM [SQL table])
```

The problem is that I don't know how to do this when there are 2 different database environments and it's within the context of the data import wizard.

How would I accomplish only selecting the records I need from the Sybase table?

EDIT:  this will be an ongoing pull...once or twice a month at least, so I'd like to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: You can do this by setting up a linked server and using four part naming.  However, I think it will probably be faster to bring the whole table into your database and run the query there.

Comment: I'm fairly certain my company doesn't permit linked servers, so that won't work.